# Regex in R for capturing words spoken by a particular speaker from conversational text

Tags: r, regex, text

I am working with the following structured text.

> MR ARMSTRONG (in English): Hi Nice to meet you. PROF FLYNN (in English): I would like to talk about global warming today. MR ARMSTRONG (in English): I concur. There is no better time to talk about this. MRS CRUZ (in English): Good idea. Global warming is an alarming issue. MS PAMELA (in English): Absolutely. MR ARMSTRONG (in English): Absolutely agree. We should spend more time on discussing potential solutions. MS HENDERSON (in English): First of all, the international community should take action.

I would like to extract the speech given by the respective participants by using regular expression. Say let’s focus on MR ARMSTRONG here.

My desired output is as follows:

> MR ARMSTRONG (in English): Hi Nice to
> meet you.  MR ARMSTRONG (in English): I concur. There is no better
> time to talk about this.  MR ARMSTRONG (in English): Absolutely agree.
> We should spend more time on discussing potential solutions.

What I can think of is the following: I know all the names of the participants in the conversation. As such, I can make use of regular expression with reference to the title and the ‘’(in English)’’.

The code is as follows:

```
Armstrong <- str_extract_all(sample_text,
'MR ARMSTRONG \\(in\\s\\w+\\)\\:.*?(?=MRS\\s\\w+\\s\\(in\\s\\w+\\):)| MR ARMSTRONG \\(in\\s\\w+\\)\\:.*?(?=PROF\\s\\w+\\s\\(in\\s\\w+\\):)| MR ARMSTRONG \\(in\\s\\w+\\)\\:.*?(?=MS\\s\\w+\\s\\(in\\s\\w+\\):)')
```

But then there seem to be some problems with the OR logical operator ‘’|’’. If I put the MRS at front before PROF and MS (like the above pattern), then the output would include what PROF FLYNN said.

> OUTPUT: "MR ARMSTRONG (in English): Hi Nice to meet you. PROF FLYNN
> (in English): I would like to talk about global warming today. MR
> ARMSTRONG (in English): I concur. There is no better time to talk
> about this. "

Another method I can think of is to capture the regular pattern of the capital letters before ‘(in English)’.

```
Armstrong_anothermethod <- str_extract_all(sample_text,'MR ARMSTRONG \\(in\\s\\w+\\)\\:.*?(?=[A-Z]\\s\\(in\\s\\w+\\):)')
```

The output is as follows:

> [[1]]  [1] "MR ARMSTRONG (in English): Hi Nice to meet you. PROF FLYN"
> [2] "MR ARMSTRONG (in English): I concur. There is no better time to
> talk about this. MRS CRU"  [3] "MR ARMSTRONG (in English): Absolutely
> agree. We should spend more time on discussing potential solutions. MS
> HENDERSO"

The problem is I do not know how to anticipate and hence get rid of the name of the next speaker after MR ARMSTRONG. It might be hard to do so as the names have irregular length. And the text only represents a small proportion of the entire text I have to deal with. Despite being capitalised and following the same pattern, there are many more names that are hard to be captured by regex like [A-Z]{1,10).

Can someone please advise on the logical operator I should use or is there any way to match all the words in capital letters (e.g. PROF FLYNN) such that my second method can work better?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

Using `regmatches` for a base R solution, we can try matching all text from `MR ARMSTRONG` up until the next two word name title or the end of the string (should Armstrong be the last entry).

```r
regmatches(txt, gregexpr("\\bMR ARMSTRONG[\\s\\S]*?(?=[A-Z]+ [A-Z]+|$)", txt, perl=TRUE))[[1]]

[1] "MR ARMSTRONG (in English): Hi Nice to meet you. "                                                          
[2] "MR ARMSTRONG (in English): I concur. There is no better time to talk about this. "                         
[3] "MR ARMSTRONG (in English): Absolutely agree. We should spend more time on discussing potential solutions. "
```

**Data:**

```
txt <- "MR ARMSTRONG (in English): Hi Nice to meet you. PROF FLYNN (in English): I would like to talk about global warming today. MR ARMSTRONG (in English): I concur. There is no better time to talk about this. MRS CRUZ (in English): Good idea. Global warming is an alarming issue. MS PAMELA (in English): Absolutely. MR ARMSTRONG (in English): Absolutely agree. We should spend more time on discussing potential solutions. MS HENDERSON (in English): First of all, the international community should take action."
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Would you mind explaining whats happening with this part of the pattern (?=[A-Z]+ [A-Z]+|$)? Sorry that i am not too familiar with regmatches.

Comment: @newabnormal The portion of the regex you mention above says to _look ahead_ and assert that what follows is either _two_ all uppercase words (i.e. is the next name) _or_ is the end of the input.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Much appreciated. As I have said in the question, some of the names outside the sample text above are of different length. Instead of PROFESSOR FLYNN (in English), it may be names like SECRETARY OF STATE (in English) and MR FOSU-MENSAH. I am struggling to find regex that completely matches the full name. Otherwise the captured text might include part of the name of the next speaker.

Comment: `Otherwise the captured text might include part of the name of the next speaker` ... no, the captured _won't_ include the name of the next speaker, because `(?= ...)` does not _match_, but rather only _asserts_ (read: checks) that a name follows.  As long as all your names have at least two all-uppercase components, my answer should be reliable here.

Answer (score 0):

If you get to the point where you *would like to extract the speech given by* all *respective participants*, you could use this:

```
strsplit(sample_text, " (?=\\w+ \\w+ \\(in English\\):)", perl=T)
```

```
[[1]]
[1] "MR ARMSTRONG (in English): Hi Nice to meet you."
[2] "PROF FLYNN (in English): I would like to talk about global warming today."
[3] "MR ARMSTRONG (in English): I concur. There is no better time to talk about this."
[4] "MRS CRUZ (in English): Good idea. Global warming is an alarming issue."
[5] "MS PAMELA (in English): Absolutely."
[6] "MR ARMSTRONG (in English): Absolutely agree. We should spend more time on discussing potential solutions."
[7] "MS HENDERSON (in English): First of all, the international community should take action."
```

It splits by a space which is followed (`(?=…)`) by one or more word characters (`\\w+`), a space, again one or more word characters and " (in English):".